# Find the number of rows in a table from metadata

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sybaseiq

I want to write a single select statement to determine the number of rows in a set of tables in Sybase IQ.

In SAS, I write this as

```
CREATE TABLE dsnobs as
SELECT libname,memname,nlobs, datetime() format DATETIME16. as timestamp
FROM dictionary.tables 
WHERE (libname=upcase('MY_LIB') & memname IN ('TABLE_1', 'TABLE_2', 'TABLE_3'));
```

For your information,

- a SAS libname is something like a table creator or table space
- the dictionary are similar to IQ SYS tables
- memname is just the name of the table

Can I do the same thing in IQ?

An approximate solution, or an indication on the space used would suit me too.

Comment: Does this help https://scn.sap.com/thread/3448070 ? SybaseIQ does not seem to have a direct ability to report on the row count :-(

Comment: Chieck this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195355/how-to-list-all-the-user-tables-in-sybase-along-with-their-row-count

Comment: Thanks @Stoleg, but I can't find `sys.systabstats` and on `sys.systables` `count` is always 0.

Comment: @Kin, I want to avoid looping over queries

Comment: What is your  product version? Try solutions from other answers from that link. Someone there is saying that accepted answer does not work, but another solution does.

Comment: For SybaseIQ 15 use table `SYSTAB`. Link: http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/zip-iq1608/iqrefbb.pdf , page 819.

Answer (score 1):

For SybaseIQ 16 (SAP IQ 16.0 SP08) use system view`SYSTAB` as:

```
select * from SYSTAB
```

Here is a link to [SyBase IQ v16 documentation](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/zip-iq1608/iqrefbb.pdf). Page **918** (correction to my comment above) says:

> Each row of the SYSTAB system view describes one table or view in the
>   database. Additional information for views  can be found in the
>   SYSVIEW system view. The underlying system table for this view is
>   ISYSTAB.
>
> Column:      count     Datatype:    UNSIGNED BIGINT     Description:
>   The number of rows in the table or mate­ rialized view. This value is
>   updated dur­ing each successful checkpoint. This number is used to
>   optimize database ac­cess. The count is always 0 for a
>   non-materialized view or remote table.

Comment: In my situation, `count` is zero, even for tables I created myself, so they should be remote :-(

Comment: You deserve the bounty, not because you solved my problem, but because of the valuable insight you brought.

Comment: @DirkHorsten, the question is why value is 0 for you. Have you done checkpoint after rows were inserted? What do you mean by "they should be remote"?

Comment: I just create them with `select ... into myschema.mytable from ...`

Comment: @DirkHorsten, As per the manual, number is updated after successful `CHECKPOINT`. Please run `CHECKPOINT` command and check system view.